# Controlling the location of objects in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've been working on this problem for a few hours. In this scenario, I have a form that allows users to select multiple classes from a select field. Each time the user selects a new class the array is updated. I have been having a lot of trouble controlling the location of the objects within the array. If the objects become out of order the select fields on the user screen changes which isn't very user-friendly.

I've managed to fix the problem using the code below, however, it seems to be quite convoluted. I was wondering if there was a 'better' or 'simpler/cleaner' way to write what I have done. I'm a fairly junior, self-taught, coder. I'm asking this because I'd like to learn.

**classes array**

```
classes = [
  {
    classId: 'yP9w2urWSz3Y4kbhN',
    active: true,
  },
  {
    classId: '3x8cNzzr4DQ4PioM7',
    active: false,
  },
];
```

** Form class select fields **

```
{this.state.classes.map((myClass) => {
  if (myClass.active) {
    return (
      <div key={myClass.classId} className="mb-3">
            <FormGroup>
              <Input
                type="select"
                name="classId"
                value={myClass.classId}
                onChange={this.handleClassSelect(myClass.classId)}
                id="classId"
              >
                <option>Select class</option>
                {myClass.options.map(eachClass => (
                  <option key={eachClass._id} value={eachClass._id}>{eachClass.name} 1 {eachClass._id}</option>
                ))}
              </Input>
              {(myClass && myClass.classError) ? <FormFeedback>{myClass.classError}</FormFeedback> : null}
            </FormGroup>
        </div>
  })})}
```

**Code to update form**

```
let newValueObject = {
  [name]: value,
  active: true,
  activeDate: new Date(),
};
const newClasses = [];

// map over the current array. Update where required and push elements into newClasses array
this.state.classes.map((myClass, index) => {
  if (myClass.classId === value) {
    newClasses.push({
      ...myClass,
      [name]: value,
      active: true,
    });
    newValueObject = {
      ...myClass,
      [name]: value,
      active: true,
    };
  }
  if (myClass.classId === classId && isNaN(myClass.classId)) {
    newClasses.push({
      ...myClass,
      [name]: classId,
      active: false,
    });
  }

  if (myClass.classId !== value && myClass.classId !== classId) {
    newClasses.push({
      ...myClass,
    });
  }
});

// Check to see if value of select field excists in newClass array
const classIdExist = newClasses.some(myClass => myClass.classId === classId);
const valueExist = newClasses.some(myClass => myClass.classId === value);
// Check the index of value
const valueIndex = newClasses.findIndex(myClass => myClass.classId === value);
// Check the index of classId
const classIdIndex = newClasses.findIndex(myClass => myClass.classId === classId);


// If select value or select classId are found in the array
// make sure array is in the correct order. The order will effect the way they
// appear on the client form.
if (classIdExist && valueExist) {
  // fix order of array
  if (classIdIndex > valueIndex) {
    newClasses.splice(classIdIndex, 0, newValueObject);
    newClasses.splice(valueIndex, 1);
  }
  if (classIdIndex < valueIndex) {
    newClasses.splice(valueIndex, 1);
    newClasses.splice(classIdIndex, 0, newValueObject);
  }
} else if (classIdExist && !valueExist) {
  // add new value
  newClasses.splice(classIdIndex, 0, newValueObject);
} else if (!classIdExist && valueExist) {
  // dont do anything, element in the right place in array
} else {
  newClasses.push(newValueObject);
}

console.log('newClasses', newClasses);
```

Comment: _controlling the location of the objects within the array._ <- is there sorting criteria for objects in the array?

Comment: Yes. See update. When the user selects a class the form sends two variables, classId and value. The form will rearrange if the array elements location changes.

Comment: @bp123 can you elaborate in words what exactly you want to achieve so it will save time for us to go through the code you want to update